# Can I display video from youtube and file system in the same field?

Tags: 7, media, files

I am using [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media) (7.x-1.4), [Media: YouTube](https://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) (7.x-2.0-rc4) and [MediaElement](https://drupal.org/project/mediaelement) (7.x-1.2) modules for drupal 7.

I have a video field where you can upload videos or enter a youtube url, thanks to the media module.

The problem is, I cannot display videos from the two sources. If I choose "rendered file" in the "Manage display" settings, the youtube video displays, but the local file is given as a link. If I choose "media element video", then the local video is displayed, but the youtube one will not.

Is there a way that I can display videos from both sources?

Comment: Would adding one field set up for "rendered file", and one field set up for "Manage display" be an option?

Comment: @FelixEve yes, but not the best option.

Comment: best thing is you have to submit a bug in module issue page!

Comment: Check the settings for your image file type in the file entity area (admin/config/media/file-types). You should be able to configure how things display. Also, I'm not sure in this case but generally I would guess media youtube 2.x is for media 2.x and 1.x is for 1.x. The info file doesn't specifiy this though so maybe in this case they are not linked like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Video Embed Field Module:**

You need to use Video Embed Field module. This is enabled in filed type in MANAGE FILEDS.If you select a filed to Video Embed and select a widget to Video.
as WELL as MANAGE DISPLAY that  select  format to Video Player. and you add a youtube url to content type that display video format.